# Update iPad application to universal application

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, app-store, ios-universal-app

If I release to appStore application which is compatible with iPad only.
Can I release update to this application which will be universal (compatible with iPhone, iPod, iPad..)?

Do I need only to recreate my app or I must to do something more?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, I have done it.

Depending on how you have made your app, xibs or Storyboards will determine how you do it.

for Storyboards

If going from iPhone to iPad:

1. Duplicate storyboard rename it:  MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard (include .storyboard)
2. Inside xCode: right click on the new storyboard -> “open as” -> “Source Code”
3. Search for targetRuntime line near the top =`"iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"`and change it to `targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"`

This will create an additional iPhone storyboard.  Adjust your artwork/views in the new storyboard as necessary to fit the iPhone screens

Check in the summary screen that the deployment info  Main Storyboard is set to the correct storyboards for iPhone and iPad respectively

Submit as an update.

If your using xibs you can duplicate and rename them ~iPad if going from iPhone to universal or ipad app, not sure about the other way around for xibs

**No new bundle ID needed**

Comment: My project is on cocos2d-iphone framework, I must recreate many things... But generraly you answer my question, I didn't need to create new project, I didn't need to register new app with new bundleId. Only I need to recreate my app to universal and submit update. Right?

Comment: That is correct.  You do not need a new BundleID to go from an iPad only app to a Universal app, or vice-versa.

Comment: Yes Faraona as Axeva said, just submit as an update no new bundle ID needed.